# How do I set a variable to be the total count of values of another variable?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /a "counter=0"
set "cycle7zForw=273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8"

for /l %%N in (1 1 12) do (
  set /a "counter+=1"
  call :therest
)
set cycle
pause
exit

:therest
for /f "tokens=%counter%" %%i in ("%cycle7zForw%") do set cycle7zForw%%N=%%i
exit /b
```

How do I set a variable that counts the number of values inside `cycle7zForw` and then put it in `for /l %%N in (1 1 %variable%) do (`

On my example, it counts 12, but I don't want to manually write 12, because there could be any number of values inside `cycle7zForw`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve with a different approach.

This replaces the spaces into linefeeds.
Then a single FOR /F loops through all numbers.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /a "counter=0"
set "cycle7zForw=273 256 192 128 96 64 48 32 24 16 12 8"
set temp=!cycle7zForw: =^

!

for /f "delims=" %%i in ("!temp!") do (
    set /a counter+=1
    set cycle!counter!=%%i
)
set cycle
```